# Match/group the colour of multiple objects

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, color

New to Blender and have been learning a lot from [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0&t=693s) videos.

My little person is "cloned" using Geometry Nodes.
[image: Output]
[image: Geometry Nodes]

I'm applying the colour changes using a constant `ColorRamp`.
[image]

However, I can't work out how to get the head the same colour as the body.

From what I've learned, the obvious answer would be to apply the material to the collection in the same way one can add a `Collection Info` modifier (if that's the right term) but it doesn't appear to allow this.

The next challenge will be to get groups of people in the same colour. i.e. Group 1 - Red, Group 2 - Blue, etc, resulting in something like:

[image]

Blender File: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqWYSrSaFDkV2xwaH5Vi7SI-PIws?e=ScpP9l

Blender version: 3.3.1, on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you make just one object (join body and head) for your person since they are looking all the same anyway? if you wanna have help with GN setup pls show us your node setup so we know how you made it. There are a lot of ways to do things in GN and so it's easier to adjust your solution or...even better, provide your blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything on our own. THx.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I've added a screenshot of the GN setup. Working out how to attach a file...

Answer (score 1):

Joining the head and the body in *Object Mode* (select both > <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>) before distributing them would be the easiest way of doing it, but I'm going to assume that you have your reasons for not wanting to do that and you'd like a procedural method to manage it in *Geometry Nodes* itself. Here's one idea:

[image]

I'm realizing the two instances (the head and the body) first, just so I can make a new, single *Instance* out of them, and *then* use that new object for distribution. Since they're a single, unified object now, they're gonna be colored together. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, honestly—I don't like realizing instances if I don't have to, for performance reasons, but it does work.

**Note:** *Geometry to Instance* node is necessary here only because you've enabled *Pick Instance* on the *Instance on Points* node. Since you're distributing a single instance with this setup, there's nothing to pick anyways, so you could turn that off and not use *Geometry to Instance* either.

Answer (score 1):

With this node tree you can color groups of your people by just adding cubes, raycast on these cubes to decide which group colors should be taken.

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

and of course...you can create a text object, convert to mesh, extrude and use this to color your people:

[image]